# kafka how to implement exactly-once message delivery logic with topic/partition/offset

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I manage to get the topic/partition/offset in method annotated with @KafkaListener,  but how can i use these data to implement a exactly-once consumer logic ?

I'm using ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory with setting of concurrenc=4, and set the  AckMode to MANUAL.
My current way is using redis to dedup:
I use topic:partition as redis key, offset as its value, then compare the coming offset with the value in redis, if the offset is newer(greater) than redis one, then go on the business logic, else I ignore the  message. finally commit the offset(ack.acknowledge())

but this way not work, for example, if the rebalance happen before ack.acknowledge() finish, then it came out this error :org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException,

and after rebalancing , the original partition is assigned to another thread, which cause the same message will be consume twice.

so in one word, how to design a logic that can make each kafka message delivery exactly-once ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write out the last offset processed atomically, along with the results of the processing, outside of Kafka. This can be to a database or file, just don't do two writes, make it a single atomic write of both data and offset. If your consumer crashes and it or another instance restarts or takes over, you need to make sure that first it reads the last offset stored with the last processing results and seek() to that position before you poll() for more messages. This is how many of the existing Kafka Sink Connectors can achieve EOS consumption today.

Comment: good idea ! so to achieve this  I need to abandon the spring-kafka  and turn to  the kafka official low level APIs

Comment: I don't know the spring-kafka apis well enough to comment but you can do this kind of exactly once with either the Kafka Consumer API or the Kafka Connect API. In the near future you will be able to use the Kafka Streams API and not have to store anything outside of Kafka because Kafka itself will support transactional writes.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka does not support exactly once yet. It will be available in the 0.11.0.0 release : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4923
This release is planned for 14 June 2017, so you can wait or build this complex logic yourself ;-)

Comment: I know kafka does not support it for now, I just wonder if there is a way we can implement it by ourselves...

Comment: This might me an interesting read/starting point : http://brooker.co.za/blog/2014/11/15/exactly-once.html

Comment: The exactly-once-semantics coming in kafka v0.11 will be: 1. from the point of view of the producer, and 2. from the point of view of kafka-streams applications. However, this is not exactly-once from the point of view of kafka->kafka consumer. Users of generic consumers still have to implement atomic persistence of offset and application state if its stored in external storage.